# Noise transmission characteristics of dome structures?

Tags: sound-proofing, noise, noise-reduction

Is a dome structure (e.g. geodome or binishell) more or less likely to transmit inside noise to the outside world, compared to the usual parallelepiped structure, at equal other conditions (same building materials, same volume, etc)?

Comment: _usual parallelepiped structure_ - What is that?  Are you talking about residential buildings or something else?  Normally we'd worry about outside noise getting inside.  Did you mean to ask about inside noise getting out?

Comment: This is a seriously complicated problem to analyse, you need to thing about the natural frequencies of the individual parts and how they act when in contact. Not something that can be attempted from a couple of quick calculations...

Comment: I find it dubious that there would be much of a difference. If you have the goal of preventing noise transmission, I think the quality of the materials and construction will dwarf the actual shape of the structure. I'd go for a traditional shape, just because of difficulty getting someone skilled both in noise transmission and dome construction.

Comment: @  JPhi1618 - I am talking about residential buildings and I mean exactly preventing inside noise from getting out.